# Sort Contacts into Smart Group if Company Box is Checked

Tags: macos, applescript, contacts, osx-mountain-lion

I found an Applescript at [apple's support site](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1534849) to sort any contact with the "Company" checkmark checked into a "Business" group:

```
property groupName : "Business"
tell application "Contacts"
    if (name of groups as list) does not contain groupName then
        make new group at end of groups with properties {name:groupName}
    end if
    repeat with singlePerson in people
        if company of singlePerson is true then
            if (people of group groupName as list) does not contain (singlePerson as list) then
                make new person at end of group groupName with data singlePerson
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
    save
end tell
```

It fails on:

```
            make new person at end of group groupName with data singlePerson
```

With error:

```
error "Contacts got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

**Does anyone know of a method to sort out all contacts checkmarked as "Company"?**

For example I do NOT want anyone who has a company name but is an individual card:

[image]

But I DO want companies with the `Company` box checkmarked:

[image]

Note:  I was directed to SO for a programmatic answer from Ask Different where I posted [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169136/sort-contacts-marked-as-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `duplicate` command to copy a person into a group (doesn't work on smart group)

```
property groupName : "Business"
tell application "Contacts"
    if (name of groups) does not contain groupName then
        make new group at end of groups with properties {name:groupName}
    end if
    with timeout of 600 seconds
        set tIDs to id of people of group groupName
        repeat with singlePerson in (get people whose its company is true)
            if tIDs does not contain id of singlePerson then
                duplicate singlePerson to group groupName
            end if
        end repeat
        save
    end timeout
end tell
```

Comment: `error "Contacts got an error: AppleEvent timed out." number -1712`

Comment: I added a longer timeout in the script